# GaussianMixture initialization using component parameters - sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, gaussian, mixture

I want to use [sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html) to store a gaussian mixture model so that I can later use it to generate samples or a value at a sample point using `score_samples` method. Here is an example where the components have the following weight, mean and covariances

```
import numpy as np
weights = np.array([0.6322941277066596, 0.3677058722933399])
mu = np.array([[0.9148052872961359, 1.9792961751316835], 
               [-1.0917396392992502, -0.9304220945910037]])
sigma = np.array([[[2.267889129267119, 0.6553245618368836], 
                        [0.6553245618368835, 0.6571014653342457]], 
                       [[0.9516607767206848, -0.7445831474157608], 
                        [-0.7445831474157608, 1.006599716443763]]])
```

Then I initialised the mixture as follow

```
from sklearn import mixture
gmix = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=2, covariance_type='full')
gmix.weights_ = weights   # mixture weights (n_components,) 
gmix.means_ = mu          # mixture means (n_components, 2) 
gmix.covariances_ = sigma  # mixture cov (n_components, 2, 2)
```

Finally I tried to generate a sample based on the parameters which resulted in an error:

```
x = gmix.sample(1000)
NotFittedError: This GaussianMixture instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

As I understand GaussianMixture is intended to fit a sample using a mixture of Gaussian but is there a way to provide it with the final values and continue from there?

Comment: First you need to feed your data into the model to train it, then only it can generate random samples. See the [documentation of sample()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.sample)

Comment: I don't have an initial data what I have is each component's parameters. I am looking for a workaround or an alternative python library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You rock, J.P.Petersen!
After seeing your answer I compared the change introduced by using `fit` method. It seems the initial instantiation does not create all the attributes of `gmix`. Specifically it is missing the following attributes,

```
covariances_
means_
weights_
converged_
lower_bound_
n_iter_
precisions_
precisions_cholesky_
```

The first three are introduced when the given inputs are assigned. Among the rest, for my application the only attribute that I need is `precisions_cholesky_` which is cholesky decomposition of the inverse covarinace matrices. As a minimum requirement I added it as follow,

```
gmix.precisions_cholesky_ = np.linalg.cholesky(np.linalg.inv(sigma)).transpose((0, 2, 1))
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that it has a check that makes sure that the model has been trained. You could trick it by training the GMM on a very small data set before setting the parameters. Like this:

```
gmix = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=2, covariance_type='full')
gmix.fit(rand(10, 2))  # Now it thinks it is trained
gmix.weights_ = weights   # mixture weights (n_components,) 
gmix.means_ = mu          # mixture means (n_components, 2) 
gmix.covariances_ = sigma  # mixture cov (n_components, 2, 2)
x = gmix.sample(1000)  # Should work now
```

Answer (score 2):

To understand what is happening, what `GaussianMixture` first [checks that it has been fitted](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/mixture/base.py#L379):

```
self._check_is_fitted()
```

Which triggers [the following check](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/mixture/gaussian_mixture.py#L681):

```
def _check_is_fitted(self):
    check_is_fitted(self, ['weights_', 'means_', 'precisions_cholesky_'])
```

And finally the [last function call](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f65d144e3966113d3daec836e443c6d7a5b/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L651):

```
def check_is_fitted(estimator, attributes, msg=None, all_or_any=all):
```

which only checks that the classifier already has the attributes.

---

So in short, the only thing you have missing to have it working (without having to `fit` it) is to set `precisions_cholesky_` attribute:

```
gmix.precisions_cholesky_ = 0
```

should do the trick (can't try it so not 100% sure :P)

However, if you want to *play safe* and have a consistent solution in case scikit-learn updates its contrains, the solution of @J.P.Petersen is probably the best way to go.

Comment: Ya that explains something, I initial tied to assign `gmix.precisions_cholesky_ = None`, with that I was able to generate samples. However this will not work if you are calling  `score_samples`, which expects the value to be a numpy array with dimension similar to the covariance.

Answer (score 0):

As a slight alternative to @hashmuke's answer, you can use the precision computation that is used inside GaussianMixture directly:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import invwishart as IW
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture as GMM
from sklearn.mixture._gaussian_mixture import _compute_precision_cholesky

n_dims = 5
mu1 = np.random.randn(n_dims)
mu2 = np.random.randn(n_dims)
Sigma1 = IW.rvs(n_dims, 0.1 * np.eye(n_dims))
Sigma2 = IW.rvs(n_dims, 0.1 * np.eye(n_dims))
gmm = GMM(n_components=2)
gmm.weights_ = np.array([0.2, 0.8])
gmm.means_ = np.stack([mu1, mu2])
gmm.covariances_ = np.stack([Sigma1, Sigma2])
gmm.precisions_cholesky_ = _compute_precision_cholesky(gmm.covariances_, 'full')
X, y = gmm.sample(1000)
```

And depending on your covariance type you should change `full` accordingly as input to `_compute_precision_cholesky` (will be one of `full`, `diag`, `tied`, `spherical`).